# AWS describe-instances filter by tag and exclude by tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, jmespath

In the new AWS console I can do inverse search, i.e.: search that does not match a certain value, [with a filter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Filtering.html).

I am trying to achieve the same using the AWS cli v2. It's straight forward to filter by tag but how do I **exclude** a tag at the same time?

```bash
aws ec2 describe-instances \
  --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId]' \
  --filter "Name=tag:MYTAG,Values=MYVALUE" \
  --output text
```

I'm trying to get a list of instances with a certain tag but at the same time exclude some of those instances based on another tag.

For example: Lets say I have instances with the following tags:

```
tag: env | value: dev
tag: eks | value: true
```

I want to build a list of instances with the key-value pair of `env`/`dev` but want to **exclude** them if they **also** have the key-value pair of `eks`/`true`.

I can see JMESPath has a boolean for [`contains`](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#contains) but I'm struggling to get anywhere with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `contains` will not really lead you anywhere, because, the mere fact that the `Tags` array contains `"Key": "eks"`, won't tell you much without the associated value.
And if you go on dissociating the `Key` and `Value`, it will be a nightmare to find back which is what.

Here is an oversimplified example to actually do the tag filtering — in an inclusive way:

```
Reservations[]
.Instances[?
  Tags[?Key == `env` && Value == `dev`]
].[InstanceId]
```

With this, we are stating that we want all instances having a tag object that would have **both** its `Key` equal to `env` **and** its `Value` equal to `dev`.

Now, we can add an [and expression](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#and-expressions) and further filter it

```
Reservations[]
.Instances[?
  Tags[?Key == `env` && Value == `dev`]
  && Tags[?Key == `eks` && Value == `false`]
].[InstanceId]
```

Now, we also account for the object having the tag `eks` with a value of `false`.

You will still miss some case with this, though, because you also have to account for instances that are totally missing the `eks` tag. And this one is a bit trickier:

```
Reservations[]
.Instances[?
  Tags[?Key == `env` && Value == `dev`] 
  && (
    !not_null(Tags[?Key == `eks`]) 
    || Tags[?Key == `eks` && Value == `false`]
  )
].[InstanceId]
```

Ends up being the final expression you need. We added here an [or expression](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#or-expressions) that allows our previous query to also filter instances that do not have an `eks` tag, with a double negation (we do not want any object that have a non-empty array of `eks` tags, so we want all the one that do have an empty `eks` array).

So, your command line ends up being:

```bash
aws ec2 describe-instances \
  --query 'Reservations[]
    .Instances[?
      Tags[?Key == `env` && Value == `dev`] 
      && (
        !not_null(Tags[?Key == `eks`]) 
        || Tags[?Key == `eks` && Value == `false`]
      )
    ].[InstanceId]' \
  --output text
```

---

*Side note: A further simplification of the above query could be*

```
Reservations[]
.Instances[?
  Tags[?Key == `env` && Value == `dev`] 
  && (
    !not_null(Tags[?Key == `eks`]) 
    || Tags[?Key == `eks` && !Value]
  )
].[InstanceId]
```

*As the `Value` field should be a boolean already, we can just negate it with a [not expression](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#not-expressions).*

Comment: Confirmed this works! Thank you for the detailed explanation.